# Can I wake up my laptop when I plug in monitor?

Tags: windows-8, laptop, display, toshiba-laptop

Do you know if there is an option to make your laptop wake from sleep/hibernation when you plug in a monitor?

I have a windows 8 toshiba laptop, and I would like to be able to just take it out of my bag, put it on my desk, plug the monitor into it and have it run. When the laptop is already running it can tell when the monitor gets plugged in, so can the same be done for when its off?

Comment: I don't believe so, no. What exact port are you connecting the monitor to? e.g. DVI, HDMI, VGA etc.?

Comment: Im using a VGA port

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't because a VGA cable only can send data from the computer to the monitor. Sorry.